# React router doesn't function intended way

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I have a React application with two routes. One to `'/'` and the other to `'/login'`. But when switched to the `'/login'` route using a `Link` component in main app(`'/'`) nothing happens. But if I manually typed `'/login'` in the browser and press enter the route get rendered. Any clue?

EDIT: after switching to `'/login'` route from main app and then reloading the route get rendered too.

Routes:

```
function App() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Route exact path="/" component={MainApp}></Route>
            <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginApp}></Route>
        </Router>
    )
}
```

Links

```
 <Router>
                <Menu mode="horizontal" defaultSelectedKeys={["Home"]} style={{ position: "fixed", zIndex: 1, width: "100%", top: "0" }}>

                    <Menu.Item key="Home" icon={<HomeOutlined />}>
                        <Link to="/" onClick={() => { props.setSearchValue(""); props.setCountry("") }}>Home</Link>
                    </Menu.Item>
                    <Menu.Item key="Login">
                        <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
                    </Menu.Item>
</Menu>
</Router>
```

Comment: Hi, can you post the code that handles the routing?

Comment: Please post code of Link

Comment: Also please add the code of import of Link

Comment: Remove `<Router>` from your `Links` component. You do not need to wrap `Link` with `Router`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `Menu` a parent component or it is a child component, if it is a child component where is it's parent is it: `MainApp` or `LoginApp`?

Comment: Menu is a child component of the Navbar component which parent is MainApp

Comment: Remove the `Router` that is wrapping `<Menu/>` then try again. good luck

Comment: Yep that was the reason